# SQL query to split a column based on hardcoded values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table eg assume this setup

table **MyTable** has various columns **Id**,  **UserId**, col1, col2 col3 including column called **Stuff**.

I want to output certain Columns from MyTable with a query
but i want to split the 'Stuff' column such that 2 new columns are shown in the query

I can define the categories hardcoded, im not sure how this can be represented in sql

```
Categoy1 = "alpha, bravo, delta, gamma';
Categoy2 = "charlie, echo, hotel';



MyTable

ID |    UserID |      Stuff       | Other Cols....
----------------------------------------------------------
1          1          alpha
2          2          hotel
3          1          charlie
4          1          echo
5          1          gamma
6          2          bravo
7          2          delta
```

i want the select query to show

```
UserId  |  Category1           |  Catergory2
----------------------------------------------------------
1            alpha, gamma            charlie, echo
---------------------------------------------------------
2            bravo, delta            hotel
----------------------------------------------------------
```

i.e produce 2 columns split based on whether the stuff column contains an item from category1 or category2
based on a distinct userId  the categories content can be comma separated as hown above

Please can you show how this can be done

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Is the category limited to 2?

Comment: no neither category is limited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xml extensions to concatenate your strings, then just hard code the categories into each subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT, UserID INT, [Stuff] VARCHAR(300))
INSERT #T VALUES
    (1, 1, 'alpha'),
    (2, 2, 'hotel'),
    (3, 1, 'charlie'),
    (4, 1, 'echo'),
    (5, 1, 'gamma'),
    (6, 2, 'bravo'),
    (7, 2, 'delta');

SELECT  UserID,
        [Category1] = STUFF((   SELECT  ', ' + [Stuff]
                                FROM    #T t2
                                WHERE   [Stuff] IN ('alpha', 'bravo', 'delta', 'gamma')
                                AND     t.UserID = t2.UserID
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''),
        [Category2] = STUFF((   SELECT  ', ' + [Stuff]
                                FROM    #T t2
                                WHERE   [Stuff] IN ('charlie', 'echo', 'hotel')
                                AND     t.UserID = t2.UserID
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT UserID
            FROM    #T
        ) t
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cabab/1)**

You could define your categories at the start in a CTE (`Categories`) for improved readibility:

```
WITH Categories AS
(   SELECT  Category, Name
    FROM    (VALUES
                (1, 'alpha'), 
                (1, 'bravo'), 
                (1, 'delta'), 
                (1, 'gamma'),
                (2, 'charlie'),
                (2, 'echo'), 
                (2, 'hotel')
            ) t (Category, Name)
), Data AS
(   SELECT  UserID, [Stuff], Category
    FROM    T
            INNER JOIN Categories c
                ON c.Name = T.[Stuff]
)
SELECT  UserID,
        [Category1] = STUFF((   SELECT  ', ' + [Stuff]
                                FROM    Data t2
                                WHERE   Category = 1
                                AND     t.UserID = t2.UserID
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''),
        [Category2] = STUFF((   SELECT  ', ' + [Stuff]
                                FROM    Data t2
                                WHERE   Category = 2
                                AND     t.UserID = t2.UserID
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT UserID
            FROM    T
        ) t
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cabab/8)**

Comment: Great answer, i'm about to give this a go, is there any way the 2 categeories can be defined outside this?

Comment: what do i need for xml extensions? i get a error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.'

Comment: You should not need anything, which method are you using?

Comment: Yes. It inserts a value into a string at a specified position, so when I have done `STUFF((SELECT...), 1, 2, '')`, it is inserting '' between after characters and replacing 2 characters. This removes the comma from the start of the concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

My try, the technique I learned from Stack Overflow!... Please check:

```
DECLARE @Categoy1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'alpha, bravo, delta, gamma',
        @Categoy2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'charlie, echo, hotel'
SELECT 
    UserID,      
    STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + display_term
       FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"'+ ',' + @Categoy1  + '"', 1033, NULL, 0) INNER JOIN 
            YourTable T on display_term=[Stuff]
            WHERE T.UserID= x.UserID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') Category1,
    STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + display_term
       FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"'+ ',' + @Categoy2  + '"', 1033, NULL, 0) INNER JOIN 
            YourTable T on display_term=[Stuff]
            WHERE T.UserID= x.UserID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') Category2
FROM YourTable x
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: This is nice use of the function `sys.dm_fts_parser`, but it also seems superfluous, why hard code something that requires a function to get in the right format? It is easier to just hard code it in the format required. In addition it is best to use `.value` when using XML extensions to concatenate strings, if there are any special characters within the text the above method will escape them (e.g. ">"), whereas using .value will preserve them.

Comment: Yeah... thanks @GarethD for notifying... It happened while copying.